# Break inheritence at itemlist level inside my SPFX webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx

I'm facing this error while using the endpoint below, to break the inheritance of permissions at itemlist level:

```
const spHttpClient: SPHttpClient = this.context.spHttpClient;
    spHttpClient.get(wUri + `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ValueTrailStep1')/items('1')/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=false,clearSubscopes=true)`  
    , SPHttpClient.configurations.v1).then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
      response.json().then((result) => {
          console.log(result);

      });
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It states clearly that we cannot use GET to issue the rest call ,you need create the REST header, REST end point and issue a POST request.

Refer below reference : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/fc34aa/break-inheritance-and-add-role-permissions-using-rest-api-in/

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a POST request to break role inheritance.

In the current REST API call, you are making a GET request. It will not work.

Modify your code as below:

```
const spHttpClient: SPHttpClient = this.context.spHttpClient;

var queryUrl = wUri + `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ValueTrailStep1')/items('1')/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=false,clearSubscopes=true)`

const spOpts: ISPHttpClientOptions = {};

spHttpClient.post(queryUrl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,spOpts).then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
    console.log(response);
    if(response.ok){
        console.log("success brreaking role inheritance");
    }
});
```

Also, ensure that your import statement is somewhat as below:

```
import { SPHttpClient, ISPHttpClientOptions, SPHttpClientResponse } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
```

Comment: Hey @souf , did you try the above code ? Did it work for you ? If yes, could you please mark it as answer. Thanks !